# Euler graph and Eulerian path

Tags: graph-theory

is it always true that if a graph contains a Eulerian path(at least one) then it will always be a Euler graph?

I know that all the vertices of a graph should be of even degree to become a Euler graph as well as the graph should be connected too, but was having this self-doubt.

EDIT: 
what about this graph:

[image]

Euler or not ?

Comment: that's the doubt .... first i was going with this definition -" a euler graph should contain a euler path i.e should be able to walk on all edges without repeating any edge " then i found some graphs which contains an eulerian path but they were not euler graph as all vertices was not having even degree.

Comment: A straight line graph has an obvious Euler path, for instance, but no cycles at all.  Even the graph with two vertices connected by a single edge has an Euler path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianGraph.html) an Euler graph is a graph containing an Eulerian cycle. There surely are examples of graphs with an Eulerian path, but not an Eulerian cycle. Consider two connected vertices for example.

EDIT: The link also mentions some authors define an Euler graph as a connected graph where every vertex has even degree. It is by no means trivial to show equivalence between these definition, but one of the two implications is pretty easy. If a graph has a Eulerian cycle, then every vertex must be entered and left an equal amount of times in the cycle. Since every edge can only be visited once, we find an even amount of edges per vertex. ($2$ times the amount of times the vertex is visited in the cycle)

Comment: edited the question, explain with that graph -Euler or not.

Comment: It has an Eulerian path, but not an Eulerian cycle. Hence, accordint to Wolfram Mathworld the graph is not an Euler graph.